# Overloading Index method of Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Overload the "Index" method to be like `myapp.com/Category/SomethingHere/`.

### The problem

I have `CategoryController` with `Index()` method as this:

```
//
// GET: /Category/
public ActionResult Index(string categoryName)
{
    if (categoryName != null)
        return View(categoryName);
    else
    {
        return Content("Test");
    }
}
```

And works normally¹ until I access `myapp.com/Category/Cars/` or `myapp.com/Category/Sports/`.

The response I received when I try to access these URLs is:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.

### What I've already tried

At `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "CategoriesMapping",
     url: "{controller}/{categoryName}",
     defaults: 
         new { controller = "Categoria", action = "Index", 
                     categoryName = URLParameters.Optional 
             }
 );
```

But with no success and the problem is the same.

### Considerations

Other things I have already tried:

```
public ActionResult Index(string? categoryName) { }
```

and

```
public ActionResult Index(Nullable<string> categoryName) { }
```

Success? No. Visual Studio returns me an error when I use this syntax

> The type "string" must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter "T" in the generic type or method "System.Nullable".

### Observations

¹: "Normally" means: if I access `myapp.com/Category/`, `Test` is showed for me.

### Ambiguous question?

Maybe. Unfortunately, no other answer that I found here — on Stack — worked for me. I have already tried [this question by Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078543/c-sharp-mvc-3-action-overloading), [this question by Papa Burgundy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc), [this question by Andy Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572788/mvc3-overloading-the-index-action-getting-500-errors) and some others.

Comment: String is a reference type. Nullable<T> is for value types only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have routes like this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "CategoriesMapping",
     url: "Category/{categoryName}",
     defaults: 
         new { controller = "Categoria", action = "Index", 
                     categoryName = URLParameters.Optional 
             }
 );

routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: 
         new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                     id = URLParameters.Optional 
             }
 );
```

Notice that the constraint says first segment has to be exactly "Category". This makes sure default route still gets to handle all other requests. You have to keep the default route to not the break the convention for other controllers. Also make sure default route is mapped last.